# Photo location on IPhone 5s

Tags: photos, iphone, geolocation

How can I determine the location a photo was taken on my iPhone 5s?  I've tried the photo app on the phone but the information is too general.

Answer (score 2):

At present, third party applications offer better access to photo metadata than the built-in Photos app on the iPhone.

For example, [Photo Investigator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-investigator-view-remove/id571574618?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4), can show you the specific GPS co-ordinates recorded in the picture's meta-data. Photos contain GPS data that's only as accurate as your phone's GPS system happened to be at the time the photo was shot. For example, a Photo Investigator screen shot shows:

[image]

That gives you the latitude, longitude and altitude metadata. I'll caution that this is the exact same data that's used to show the pin for the photo in the Photos application. So it's not any more accurate, though it is text-based so you can use the co-ordinates in other mapping software like Google Maps or Google Earth if you don't like the way the location is rendered in the Maps app on your iPhone.